# Opening a socket to a web site by using proxy in java

Tags: java

I have server working as proxy ( an intermediary) to deny some web sites. I set IP address and port number of the machine where my program runs (e.g. 127.0.0.1:8080). I opened a TCP socket and listen requests from browser. When I try to enter banned web sites, I can display an error page on my browser. But if the web page that I want to enter is not banned, I should show it on my browser. I couldn't do the last part. I can't access unbanned web sites. I think I should use another socket with port 80, but I 'm not sure.

This is how I check if a web site banned or not. If banned, returning an error page. Otherwise It should display web page.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class ClientHandler2 extends Thread {

private Socket clientSocket = null;
private DataOutputStream out = null;
private BufferedReader in = null;
//  private Socket mySocket = null;


public ClientHandler2(Socket clientSocket) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
}

public void run() {


    try {
        //create input-output streams
    //  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        ReqHdr req = new ReqHdr();
        RepHdr rep = new RepHdr();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));


        if(req.parse(clientSocket.getInputStream())){
            MyReader myreader = new MyReader();
            if(myreader.IsBanned(req.url ) == true ){

                InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                String IP = addr.getHostAddress();
                Date date = new Date();
                String datestr = date.toString();
                 try{
                      // Create file 
                      FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("log.txt",true);
                      BufferedWriter log = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                      log.append("Thread with id: " + this.getId() + " Banned URL:  " + req.url + " IP: " + IP + " Access Time/Date: " + datestr + "\n");
                      //Close the output stream
                      log.close();
                      }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
                      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                      }

                out.writeUTF((rep.formForbidden()));

            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Thread with id " + this.getId() + " URL: " + req.url);


            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("error");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Her where I create a new thread whenever I try to enter to a web site.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

public class WebPolice {


public static void main(String args[])
{
    //create server socket
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
        System.out.print("WebPolice listening clients over port 8080...");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    //at each iteration of the loop, accept new incoming connection and serve the client
    while (true)
    {
        //create client socket
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {

            //accept incoming connection request
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("New client connected!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //create new thread object for the new coming client
        //note that ClientHandler extends Thread
        ClientHandler2 clientHandler = new ClientHandler2(clientSocket);

        //new power for next client

        //run the Thread which deals with the new coming client
        clientHandler.start();


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println("Thread with id " + this.getId() + " URL: " + req.url);
```

In above block, open a connection to the url using HttpURLConnection and redirect the new connection's outputstream to client's inputstream.

You need to handle POST, DELETE and other http operations separately.

Comment: hmm do you have any simple example that shows how to use HttpURLConnection

Comment: Oracle has tutorial on opening connection to url and reading its content. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html